# JavaScript strings aren't cast into HTML objects?

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple: Add a 1x20 table of input cells inside a div.

I created a JavaScript function

```
var tableHTML = function(attributes, rows, columns)
{
    var retHTML = "<table " + attributes + ">";
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        retHTML += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            retHTML += "<td>&nbsp</td>";
        retHTML += "</tr>";
    }
    return (retHTML + "</table>retHTML");
}
```

to give me the HTML for a table with a specified dimensions and attributes. Then, in the body of my HTML, I put

```
<div class="inner_div" id="input_table">
    <!-- div to house the table -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("input_table").innerHTML += tableHTML("id=\"input_table\" type=\"input\"", 1, 20);
</script>
```

which I thought would accomplish the task, but hasn't. I think this is because I'm trying to assign a string object to an HTML object. I kinda assumed that an implicit cast would be made. Anyways, I'm wondering if anyone has a "quick fix" to my problem. I would prefer not to redo my entire approach to the problem, but I also wouldn't mind someone informing me of the proper way to do the type of thing I'm trying to do -- using JavaScript to fill in page HTML on load.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger, such as Firebug or Chrome?

Comment: .innerHTML _is_ a string, to be fair your function is pretty bad though, you should really learn how to use the DOM API and construct the table with it rather than with strings. Look at createElement and appendChild.

Comment: Also, can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on this. I'm learning functional programming, so I do a bunch things here that might seem like their a waste of coding, but here's the concept:

- Get the dimensions
- Create a single row
- Copy that row to make the table
- After that return the table.

If you want to add id's, class's, etc... work with the DOM element returned by makeTable.

```
// Makes a single row
var makeRow = function(_columns) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    var cols = _columns;
    while (cols) {
      row.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true));
      cols--;   
    }
    return row;
}

// Makes a table
var makeTable = function(_rows, _columns) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var row = makeRow(_columns);
    var rows = _rows;
    while (rows) {
        table.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
        rows--;   
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works: the table is generated and obviously empty

But be carrefull: if you do this, you will have two elements with the same ID (input_table)